# Could 'you were not' be used to replace 'you were away' here?

Tags: adjectives, expressions, translation, alternatives

I was making a sentence to polish up my fiction, I wrote down it out of my instinctive understanding.

> The three-year time you were not was terrible.

This is the background: during the three-year time, I fell into an endless coma and slumber.

But when I used translate machine software DeepL, it translated the sentence into 'The three-year time you were away was terrible' from my mother tongue Chinese '你不在的这三年很糟糕'.

So what is the difference between them? Is 'you were away' more natural or more correct?

Comment: 'You were not' is not idiomatic English. Neither is 'the three-year time'. The three years while you were away was terrible.

Answer (score 3):

"you were away" is correct, "you were not" is not. The closest equivalent I can think of is "you were not *here*" or "you were not *there*"; "you were not" with no further details roughly translates to "you didn't exist *at all*".

Comment: Or it invites the question "You were not what?"